# jQuery Accordion not Working Correctly

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make an Accordion type effect using HTML and JQuery(not using a plugin).

I thought it would be easy, attach a listener to the title, look up to the parent and down to the subject and show it, but nope. It does not work.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YAFqN/1/)

*HTML*

```
<div id="myAccordian">
            <div class="priv-Section">
                <div class="priv-Title">Main</div>
                <div class="priv-Body" style="display:none;">
                    Main Body
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="priv-Section">
                <div class="priv-Title">Users - CV</div>
                <div class="priv-Body"  style="display:none;">
                    CV Body
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".priv-Title").click(function () {

        $(this).parent().(".priv-Body").first().css("display", "inline");
    });
});
```

I intend to add CSS later to make this pleasing to the eye. So please excuse the bare bones structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a syntax error... and you have to use next to get the element *.priv-Body*

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert("hi");
    $(".priv-Title").click(function () {

        $(this).next(".priv-Body").css("display", "inline");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
<div id="myAccordian">
        <h3 class="priv-Title">Main</h3>
        <div class="priv-Body">Main Body</div>
        <h3 class="priv-Title">Users - CV</h3>
        <div class="priv-Body" >CV Body</div>
</div>
```

jQuery.UI

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "#myAccordian" ).accordion();
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YAFqN/5/)

Answer (score -1):

Did you even check the console?

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( on Line 25`

Line 25: `$(this).parent().(".priv-Body").first().css("display", "inline");`

Comment: OK. i saw the problem. but how is this supposed to classify as an answer?